# Does [index] refer to variable 'index' or is generic index placeholder?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm not sure what exactly 'index' in 'self.cards[index]' is referring to in this code.
I understand that [index] is itself shorthand for the objectAtIndex:index method but as it seems like in this code a local variable called index has been declared and initialised, I just want to check what index in self.cards[index] is referring to - 
namely, is it the variable index which will be a random number each time it is used, or is index here just a generic placeholder for an index?

```
-(Card *)drawRandomCard
{
Card *randomCard = nil;

if ([self.cards count]) {

unsigned index = arc4random() % [self.cards count];

randomCard = self.cards[index];

[self.cards removeObjectAtIndex:index];
}

return randomCard;
;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As others have mentioned, index is a local variable, defined right here:

```
unsigned index = arc4random() % [self.cards count];
```

The next line simply uses that variable to access an object in the array self.cards:

```
randomCard = self.cards[index];
```

This is called Objective C Subscripting - it's similar to a Literal, and is mostly just shorthand for ObjectAtIndex (some caveats apply; that's why Objective C is not a beginner's language).

For example:

```
// Fetch an object from this array, at index 2
id object = myArray[2];

// Fetch an object from this Dictionary, with key TestKey
id object = myDict@[@"TestKey"];
```

...are both valid ways to utilize subscripting with arrays and dictionaries. The code you showed simply replaces the literals ("TestKey" and "2") with actual variables.

For example, this code is equivalent:

```
// Fetch an object from this array, at index 2
int myIndex = 2;
id object = myArray[myIndex];

// Fetch an object from this Dictionary, with key TestKey
NSString *myKey = @"TestKey";
id object = myDict@[myKey];
```

Subscripting and many Literal types are fairly new to objective C. I'd recommend watching the WWDC video Modern Objective C for more information. Also, here's a quick reference: http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ObjectiveCLiterals.html

Comment: Thanks cdstamper for going to the trouble to explain that. I am teaching myself to program using stanford's ios itunes course. I'm a beginner obviously but this seems very learnable. Yes, I am aware I'm asking what could be deemed by others to be lousy questions but even in my original post I explained that I knew index was a variable, so I just needed confirmation here, and of course the extra information you have given me is of immense help also. I still don't understand why people would suggest learning a different language first, why not objective-c if one is prepared to work hard?

Comment: Thanks for accepting the answer. Quick note: Objective C does have elements of C/C++, but it's also heavily influenced by SmallTalk - a completely defunct language that's essentially completely unique. Messaging rather than methods is the biggest concept that's totally unique. Point is, it's a unique language; tougher to learn, but certainly not impossible!

Answer (score 0):

The code below will assign a value to the variable "index" between 0 and the count of cards in the array - 1.

```
unsigned index = arc4random() % [self.cards count];
```

So if there were 4 cards in the array it would return between 0 and 3.

The following line then gets that array entry and assigns it the to randomCard variable.

"index" in this instance could be replaced with a different variable name if it's confusing you, "randomCardIndex" might be a better name.

Comment: Cheers Gary. So it was referring to the variable then! Great to confirm that. Thanks a lot.

Comment: And yes, it was index used as name of variable that confused me further. I also noticed someone voted down your answer. Wonder who that was then? hot licks, you still checking in?